# Azure DevOps - Is it possible to detect that a release has been triggered by the auto-redeploy trigger?

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps I have a release pipeline that uses the auto-redeploy trigger to deploy the last successful release if the current one fails.

I have a script that I want to run *only* when a release has been requested by the auto-redeploy trigger.

Is there any way to detect that a release has been triggered in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to detect that a release has been triggered by the
>   auto-redeploy trigger

For this issue , first we can view the `Deployments` in Release pipeline to check if the deployment is triggered as expected.

[image][image]

From the figures, we can see that if the current stage deployment fails, `auto-redeploy trigger` redeploys the previous successful release, and the current release stage still displays the `failed` state. So if you set an auto-redeploy trigger and your current stage is in a failed state, then the previous release should trigger redeployment.

The previous successful release is triggered instead of the current release, so it can only be detected in `Deployments`. If you want to detect if the current release is triggered by the auto-redeploy trigger, I am afraid this is currently impossible.

In addition , you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. You can comment and vote it there. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.